# Change the kernel in downloaded Ubuntu Image

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, compiling, iso, initrd

I'm adding multiple new system calls to kernel.
I want to test my custom kernel by making an bootable ISO out of it trying to boot on another machine.

As a part of making this bootable ISO, I got hold of the Ubuntu 14.04 bootable ISO and replaced the vmlinuz.efi in the Ubuntu14.04ISO/casper with the bzImage produced after the kernel build.

This ISO didn't boot successfully.

I guess I need to make a new "inrd" too and found commands like "mkisofs" but it requires to have the custom kernel installed on my machine, which I can't do as it's a common build server.

Questions:
What all files in the ISO have to changed to make it boot my custom kernel.

Comment: There are multiple kernels on the Ubuntu 14.04 ISO (used for the live system, for installation etc). What is the Kernel with a capital K? What means it did not work out, you cannot replace the file because you don't know how to extract and recombine an ISO? Do you have an end goal (like burning the ISO image on DVD and use it as a frisbee?)

Comment: My end goal is to boot a virtual machine with the kernel I build. I know to extract the iso and make a bootable iso with mkisofs. But what I don't know is which all files I have to change to put the new kernel into an existing iso.

Comment: Do update the question with your above comment, please.

Comment: @peterph..I edited my question. Hope it is more clear now. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want to do, from your comment *"My end goal is to boot a virtual machine with the kernel I build"*, is

1. Boot a virtual machine (VM) with the current Ubuntu 14.04 ISO
2. Install Ubuntu to a virtual hard drive in the VM
3. Build/install the new kernel in the VM

Then if you really wanted, you could create a live iso from the now-updated Ubuntu. See https://duckduckgo.com/?q=remaster+live+iso for a load of info. Or:

- [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu/122506#122506) Using Remastersys

Comment: Sorry that I didn't say it well.I want to have a installation medium with my custom kernel.

Comment: So you want to remaster your own live iso... use a tool like remastersys, or google

Comment: I tried Google but could not find a working method. All end on Kernel panic. In this process do I actually need to build a new initramfs ..?